# usage of translate from python 2 to python 3

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have a legacy code from `python2.7` with in it:

```
f = lambda x:x.translate(None, "1234567890_")
```

this lambda function is used to make a string like this:

```
>> my_string = "hello_i_am_from_casablanca78"
```

to look like this:

```
>> print f(my_string)
>> "helloiamfromcasablanca"
```

In `python3` this is no longer working, is there another simple way to do this?

Because I've tried on `python3` and I get the following error:

```
'str' does not support the buffer interface
```

if I remove the encoding I get this:

```
TypeError: translate() takes exactly one argument (2 given)
```

Many thanks.

Comment: `def f(s): return ''.join(c for c in s if not c in '1234567890_')`?

Comment: @JohnColeman Great ! Can you post this as answer so I can close this ? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is one way to get [`translate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) to work in python3: you create a table using [`mktrans`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans) first:

```
tr_tbl = str.maketrans('','' , "1234567890_")
print('hello_i_am_from_casablanca78'.translate(tr_tbl))
```

Comment: Just to stay coherent with the initial question based on your answer, this is what I needed: f = lambda x: x.translate(str.maketrans('','', '1234567890_'))

Comment: correct! ...that would have been a more complete answer indeed.

Answer (score 1):

That lambda seems too obscure to salvage.

More simply you could just use:

```
def f(s): 
    return ''.join(c for c in s if not c in '1234567890_'
```